# Swift instantiate from generic type

Tags: swift, generics, objectmapper

I have a class implementing Mappable protocol and I want to pass the type as parameter to a function and get an instance of that object, but the type might also be a primitive type.

```
class MyMappable : Mappable {

    required init?(map: Map) {

        print("i am custom mappable")
    }
}

func getInstance<T>() -> T{

    if T.self == Int.self {

        return 10 as T
    }

    if T.self is Mappable.self {
        return T(Json : [:]) //this is the problem, T is not Mappable
    }

}
```

What I tried is create 2 override for getInstance like this :

```
func getInstance<T>() -> T{}

func getInstance<T : Mappable>() -> T{}
```

but for more types it can be lots of override.
is there a way to let swift know T is mappable in first function?

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally cast it to a Mappable like this (untested):

```
if let MappableType = T.self as? Mappable.self {
    return MappableType(Json : [:])
}
```

Usually variable names are lowercase but in this case I can imagine using uppercase since it is used as a type.

You could also do it differently depending on your usage/callsite.

How about constraining the `getInstance<T>() -> T` method:

`getInstance<T: Mappable>() -> T`